# J bolt protruding through wall

Tags: foundation

[image]

We have a j bolt protruding through the wall of our concrete foundation after only 1 year. What is code for fixing this. According to our builder the steel isn’t needed and they can just patch the concrete.

Answer (score 1):

The “J” bolt is required. The size and spacing is determined on where you are located (seismic zone, wind loading requirements, etc.).

This problem is caused by carelessness. That is to say, the anchor bolt was placed too close to the edge of the foundation wall, (and the wall seems to step back which was not accounted for in the placement of the bolt.)

Depending on the load on the bolt, you’ll need a minimum of 2” of concrete cover over the bolt.

Anchor bolts are sized based on unusual and extreme loads...not normal loading. That bolt may be just fine until you have an earthquake or a wind storm. I’d have an architect or structural engineer (not a civil engineer) review it.

Comment: This is a load bearing wall of a 2 story house

Comment: @AmandaBerry We investigate load bearing walls for 1) vertical load (in which the j bolt would be acceptable), and 2) lateral loads (in which case it would not be acceptable). Severity of situation depends on where you live. What state do you live in? A 2 story wind loaded building requires significant resistance. The j bolt could be under severe withdrawal loads.

Comment: I live in Ohio.

Comment: @AmandaBerry Ohio isn’t known for significant earthquakes, but you do have Cat 1 hurricanes. Is the j bolt connected to a steel connector?